# Trouble with Intel HAXM 7.3.0

Tags: android, intel, processor, haxm

Intel HAXM refuses to launch with my emulator. I think I've tried everything for the past two days and I can't figure it out.

These are the errors in Android Studio.

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires
>   hardware acceleration!
>
> Emulator: CPU acceleration status: Unable to open HAXM device:
>   ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Here's the list of things I've done to fix it:
Enabled virtualization in BIOS, set Hyper V off, made sure antivirus isn't a problem, my processor supports virtualizations and everything needed for haxm to work, tried different emulators, different apis - didn't work.

I tried installing different haxm versions, it didn't solve it either.
Installed the latest version, 7.3, didn't work.

[processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVjFK.png), [error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AT7J.png),[already installed haxm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBAAc.png)

Comment: Welcome to [so].Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
07/09/2018

Issue is still not fixed but i found a smart workaround it. I'm using NOX emulator to debug the app. Nox loads the app within seconds. Just figured i'd post this if anyone is stuck here.